# what is a good design pattern for connecting a sender and a receiver?

Tags: java, design-patterns, jetty

I'm trying to implement the logic for connecting a sender and a receiver for a file transfer, the handshake between a sender and a receiver. The basic high-level workflow I'm imagining is...

> ```
> Sender   : prep for transfer, create token, wait for receiver to connect
>
> Receiver : access download URL using token, wait for sender to start sending
>
> Sender   : confirm Receiver has connected / is waiting, send
>
> Receiver : receive
> ```

***note**: there can only be one receiver to a sender, meaning only 1 receiver can "download" the file the sender is sending

I'm using [Jetty Continuations](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Continuations) for long-polling the server which makes handling asynchronous events easy, but I'm not sure how to approach the design aspect. What is a good design pattern for the above workflow, * **the handshake** * between a sender and a receiver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My goto strategy is to use a JMS queue for this class of problems.  There are a variety of implementations out there with a ton of options.  You may look for "Out Of Band" file transfers specifically, which is essentially what you are describing:  Transferring a token (message) from a server that points to a file to be downloaded by the client.  Also, this fits into your 1 receiver download requirement.  A JMS queue can be configured to only allow a single client per message through transactional locking.

Don't know if this really answers your question, but it may be a place to start.

**Edit:**

If you're brand new to JMS, a good place to start would be messing around with ActiveMQ:

[Homepage link](http://activemq.apache.org/)

[Doc referencing out of band file transfer](http://activemq.apache.org/blob-messages.html)
You will probably want to implement your own "BlobMessage" or just use a regular message and handle a url passed through it.

[Oracle JMS 1.1 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncdq.html)

There are a lot of resources available for JMS because it is such an old standard.

Hope this helps!

Comment: the actual sending of the file is already implemented and works. i'm more interested in the handshake between sender/receiver

Comment: Trying to digest your question again, are you asking what strategy to use after you have downloaded the given file?

Comment: nope... i'm trying to figure out how to design the handshake between a sender and a receiver * before * the transfer begins

Comment: Ah, then my answer stands.  I would use a jms queue to handle the handshake using a message (aka token)... then download the file using your given implementation "out of band".

Comment: sounds good... can you point to me a tutorial, maybe some example code?

Comment: Added some resource links in the response.